# Align-items: stretch doesn't work in .swiper-wrapper

Tags: flexbox, swiper.js

So i'm using swiper slider. Inside .swiper we have .swiper-wrapper which has display: flex,
i want to add align-items: stretch so my items inside .swiper-wrapper have equal heights, but it doesn't work. other values for property align-items are working. How to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I have been struggling with this problem for a long time. The `height` of the `.swiper-silde` elements is set to `100%`, which in combination with `flex-shrink: 0` seems to cause them to be exactly as high as the content they contain. This explains why `align-item` values like `center`, `flex-start`, `flex-end` work as expected (because they will move the slide, but not changing it's height) while `stretch` does not.

Try:

```
.swiper-wrapper .swiper-slide {
    height: unset;
}
```

Now all values for `align-items` for the wrapper will work as expected:

```
.swiper-wrapper {
    align-items: stretch;
}
```